# getting imgae src and save images in a directory by python image crawler

Tags: python, image, web-crawler

I want to create a python image crawler.

This is what I have now:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
url = 'http://blog.pouyacode.net/'
data = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
img = soup.findAll('img')
print (img)
print ('\n')
print ('****************************')
print ('\n')
for each in img:
    print(img.get('src'))
    print ('\n')
```

This part works:

```
print (img)
print ('\n')
print ('****************************')
print ('\n')
```

But after `*****************` in the output, this errors appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "pull.py", line 15, in <module>
print(img.get('src'))
AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'get'
```

So how can I get all the SRC of all images?
And how can I save those images in a directory?

Comment: You probably mean to use each.get('src') instead of img.get('src')

Comment: yes, sorry that was a little mistake!  Thank you. But what about the second one, saving images in a folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this? Written from mind and not tested

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import os

url = 'http://blog.pouyacode.net/'
download_folder = "downloads"

if not os.path.exists(download_folder):
    os.makedirs(download_folder)

data = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
img = soup.findAll('img')

for each in img:
    url = each.get('src')
    data = urlopen(url)
    with open(os.path.join(download_folder, os.path.basename(url)), "wb") as f:
        f.write(data.read())
```